# How to delete wordpress menu

Tags: sidebar

I'm designing my product pages, but at every page at the bottom, I find this:
[image]

Does anyone know how to delete this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look in your [widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets#Displaying_Widgets). Appearance > Widgets, and remove the ones you don't want.

Comment: Big thanx! I looked in my woocommerce php files to find the problem. But this is my answer. Thanx again!